# Unload Ubuntu from PC

Tags: system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu to my PC and at age 76 I find it a little too advanced for me. I cannot find a way to unload it from my PC, can anybody help please?

Comment: If windows is still installed, then just removing the Ubuntu bootloader (grub) should be possible, here's a win7 oriented answer about it, win8 should be similar http://askubuntu.com/a/143482

Comment: Hello John, did you only download Ubuntu? Or are you also able to use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to go back to Windows and Ubuntu was a fresh install with no backup partition then stick in a windows disk advanced install format your HDD and then install windows.

Or stick with Ubuntu. I have been switching back and forth for years thinking it was too advanced for me but once you get to know it it's not that bad.